# What does this Flow error mean?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm getting an error from Flow that I don't understand.

```
Cannot call document.createTreeWalker because:
 • Either number literal 4 [1] is incompatible with number literal 1 [2].
 • Or number literal 4 [1] is incompatible with number literal 5 [3].
 • Or number literal 4 [1] is incompatible with number literal 128 [4].
 • Or number literal 4 [1] is incompatible with number literal 129 [5].
 • Or number literal 4 [1] is incompatible with number literal 132 [6].
 • Or number literal 4 [1] is incompatible with number literal 133 [7].

     hello.js
        2│
        3│ const body = document.body;
        4│ if (body) {
        5│   document.createTreeWalker(body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);
        6│ }
        7│

     /tmp/flow/flowlib_18704f10/dom.js
 [2] 1050│   createTreeWalker<RootNodeT: Node>(root: RootNodeT, whatToShow: 1, filter?: NodeFilterInterface, entityReferenceExpansion?: boolean): TreeWalker<RootNodeT, Element>;
     1051│   createTreeWalker<RootNodeT: Node>(root: RootNodeT, whatToShow: 4, filter?: NodeFilterInterface, entityReferenceExpansion?: boolean): TreeWalker<RootNodeT, Text>;
 [3] 1052│   createTreeWalker<RootNodeT: Node>(root: RootNodeT, whatToShow: 5, filter?: NodeFilterInterface, entityReferenceExpansion?: boolean): TreeWalker<RootNodeT, Element|Text>;
 [4] 1053│   createTreeWalker<RootNodeT: Node>(root: RootNodeT, whatToShow: 128, filter?: NodeFilterInterface, entityReferenceExpansion?: boolean): TreeWalker<RootNodeT, Comment>;
 [5] 1054│   createTreeWalker<RootNodeT: Node>(root: RootNodeT, whatToShow: 129, filter?: NodeFilterInterface, entityReferenceExpansion?: boolean): TreeWalker<RootNodeT, Element|Comment>;
 [6] 1055│   createTreeWalker<RootNodeT: Node>(root: RootNodeT, whatToShow: 132, filter?: NodeFilterInterface, entityReferenceExpansion?: boolean): TreeWalker<RootNodeT, Text|Comment>;
 [7] 1056│   createTreeWalker<RootNodeT: Node>(root: RootNodeT, whatToShow: 133, filter?: NodeFilterInterface, entityReferenceExpansion?: boolean): TreeWalker<RootNodeT, Text|Element|Comment>;
         :
 [1] 3508│   static SHOW_TEXT: 4;
```

It looks to me like `SHOW_TEXT` (which is 4) should be allowed, given that line 1051 lists 4 as a valid value for the second argument. What am I missing?

To reproduce this you can run:

```
git clone https://github.com/MatrixFrog/flow-example
cd flow-example
git checkout 0f6035a8bb05cc8f0f01418d4617973991baa231
flow version # 0.73.0
flow check
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the error is so unhelpful seems like an issue with Flow, but your error is that

```
filter?: NodeFilterInterface
```

accepts a filter, or `undefined`, `null` is not a valid value there, so

```
document.createTreeWalker(body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, undefined, false);
```

will pass the typechecker properly.